# Template html/javascript/css for iphone. Need to run it in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, css, uiwebview

I need an example of one template for iphone. I need to run it in my uiwebview an edit some tag with javascript. Can someone send me an example of how I can do that?
I can't understand.

Comment: What kind of template? Any template? What tag are you talking about? Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) includes a sample project you could use for that purpose.

Comment: Exactly what it says on its (linked to) homepage. A platform for writing HTML / JS based stuff for phones and thus its sample HTML/JS stuff is suitable as a starting point for use in a UIWebView.